# how to tell in Swagger docs , CORS in enabled in my API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle, openapi

I have enabled CORS in my ASP.NET Web API. 
When I generate the swagger documentation (http://localhost:2942/swagger/docs/v1 ), I am not able to find any information that points that CORS is enabled on my API. How can I enable the documentation to provide this detail that CORS is enabled.

Comment: *"I am not able to find any information that points that CORS is enabled on my API"* - what information do you expect to see? OPTIONS methods in the list? Something else? Can't you just include the necessary text in your API's `info.description`?